# Regex : Capture group 1 then remove everything aside from group 1

Tags: regex

Hi I just want to ask if what regex to use when I want to capture the group 1 then remove everything aside from the group 1.

Here is the regex editor that I'm currently using https://regex101.com/r/OY8T8J/1

```
(<h1.*?<\/table>).
```

I only need to capture the group 1

Thank you hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Just match everything and replace the string with `$1`.

Comment: @PoulBak That won't work if there are multiple matches, because "everything" will match other instances of the pattern.

Comment: What language are you using? In Python, you can use `text = ''.join(re.findall(regexp, text))` to remove everything except the matches.

Comment: Using Notepad++? Find `(<h1.*?</table>)|(?s).` and replace with `(?1$1\n)`.